# sns.regplot set limit on regression line y axis

Tags: matplotlib, data-science, seaborn, eda

For the given seaborn plot, how do we set the regression line y-axis limit within 5.
The rating never crosses 5. Is there a way to truncate/clip it?
sns.regplot(x="Reviews", y="Rating", data=df);

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g = sns.regplot(x="Reviews", y="Rating", data=df);
g.set(ylim=(None, 5))
plt.title('Rating VS Reviews')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sns.regplot(x="Reviews", y="Rating", data=df)
sns.plt.ylim(0, y_lim)
```

Change the value of `y_lim` according to your requirements